# How to mount Certificates from CertBot to use inside Docker Container

Tags: mount, docker, container, letsencrypt, certbot

The official `certbot` ( https://certbot.eff.org ) tool to issue and renew certificates from `Let's Encrypt` saves the currently valid certificate to `${prefix}/archive/${domain}/certN.pem`, where `N` is an arbitrary number.
The paths that should be used to access the currently valid certificates and keys are relative symlinks in `${prefix}/live/${domain}/cert.pem`:

```
root@skprov2:${prefix}/live/${domain}# ls
total 12K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 24 16:08 ./
4.0K drwx------ 9 root root 4.0K Aug 24 10:57 ../
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Jul 24 16:08 cert.pem -> ../../archive/${domain}/cert2.pem
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 Jul 24 16:08 chain.pem -> ../../archive/${domain}/chain2.pem
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 Jul 24 16:08 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/${domain}/fullchain2.pem
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jul 24 16:08 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/${domain}/privkey2.pem
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  682 Jul 23 09:40 README
```

When only mounting the `live` directory, programs running inside docker containers will fail loading the required certiticate data, because of the relative symlinks.

How can the latest (valid) certificate data from `certbot` be used within a Docker container?

Answer (score 4):

The relative symlinks are mapped to go up 2 layers (from `domain` folder to `live` folder, from `live` folder to `root` folder), then enter the `archive` folder and finally the `domain` subfolder within.

To avoid mounting *all* domain subdirectories, giving access to all certificate data, we have to use 2 mounts.

## Docker Host directory structure

Let's assume the following directory structure created by certbot on the Docker host:

```
/certbot/
    |-live/
    |  |-domain.com
    |  |  |-cert.pem
    |  |  |-privkey.pem
    |  |-domain2.com
    |     |-cert.pem
    |     |-privkey.pem
    |
    |-archive/
       |-domain.com
       |  |-cert.pem
       |  |-privkey.pem
       |-domain2.com
          |-cert.pem
          |-privkey.pem
```

## Mounting the subdirectories

In Docker, we only want the subdirectories for the target domain mounted inside the container.

```
docker run \
  -v /certbot/live/domain.com:/cert/live/domain.com:ro \
  -v /certbot/archive/domain.com:/cert/archive/domain.com:ro \
  myimage:tag
```

This way, programs inside the container can successfully resolve the relative paths to the `archive` folder while their configuration points to the symlinks inside the `live` folder (`/cert/live/domain.com/cert.pem`).